# How to create a temp table in a Postgres query that contains a range of dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some sparse date-related data in Postgres, and I want to extract a report that has a complete date range (even if there is no related data). I want to do the equivalent of a `left outer join` between a (non-existent) table of all dates in a range, and the data table that I have, i.e.

```
SELECT temp_dates.date, data_table.data_field
FROM temp_dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN data_table
ON temp_dates.date = data_table.data
```

My question is - how do I do create the temp table with the full range of dates?

NB I've asked about temp tables as I understand them, however if there is a better way (e.g. joining a table to an array, for instance), then I'd really like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`generate_series` on PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

get min date from your range then max and generate series

Comment: Thanks for this - generate_series is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I'm now getting unexpected results from the join. I will mark this as the answer and then open another question.

Comment: Please add an actual solution, not just a "look here for something you will use" link.